# Mysql query of inverted index data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inverted-index

I have thousand of pages in website which I parsed and stored it as Inverted Index viz

> **document**
>
> - docid (PK,FK)
> - url
> - charactercount
> - wordcount

Charactercount and wordcount helps me determine long document from short which I may use later.

> **word**
>
> - wordid (PK,FK)
> - word
> - doc_freq
> - inverse_doc_freq

For inverse_doc_freq calculation I use fictional high number (100000000) to prevent total document recalculation.

> **loc**
>
> - wordid
> - docid
> - word_freq
> - weight
>
> (wordid & docid combined unique)

The weight is a score calculated on simple basis like word in title + word in url + word frquency etc.

I am having problem framing my sql query for search words. For 3 word search I am doing like

1. Break query into each word
2. Check inverse_doc_freq for each word and remove low idf word (removal of stop word)
3. stem the remaining word (assume still 3 words remain)
4. Query for each word

It is at stage 4 that I am getting stuck ! My SQL query is like

`SELECT d.docid,url,inverse_doc_freq,word_freq,weight from document d,word w,loc l WHERE d.docid=l.docid AND w.wordid=l.wordid AND (word='word1' OR word='word2' OR word='word3') ORDER BY weight DESC`

The returned documents are not correct though. Trust I might have to Search thrice to find documents for each word and then try to find the common documents, but how ? Is it possible to use only 1 MySQL query for it ? Also is it possible to use [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) and how ?

Comment: What do you mean "The returned documents are not correct"?

Comment: There are duplicate documents. While it is best to show documents which have all 3 words, the present query shows documents with 1 common word only also if I change `OR` to `AND` then it shows zero documents. ;-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate at the document level.

```
select d.docid, d.url, sum(weight) as weight
from document d join
     loc l
     on d.docid = l.docid join
     word w
     on w.wordid = l.wordid
where w.word in ('word1', 'word2', 'word3')
group by d.docid
order by weight DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering . Why are you using `sum` and not `distinct d.docid` as later too perhaps will give single result ? Also is it possible to filter results with Documents having all 3 words ?

Comment: @jahajee.com . . . You almost never need `select distinct`.  You can just use `group by` instead.  In this case, you need `group by` for the `sum()`.

Comment: Thank you I recalculated the weight and now it seems perfect. Trust that SUM was required to add all weight calculation for each word (I did not understood before). Thanks again.