# MYSQL TRANSACTION alternative?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

Using PHP / MYSQL I am trying to create a simple search for my website. I have all pages data in `mytable` and I am processing thousands of rows in this sequence:

```
 1. Query for 1 row with a particular id in `mytable` with column `status=0`
 2. Using that id do something in `other` table(s) 
 3. When done, update `mytable` with`status=1`
```

**EDITED**

In step 2 I process all data from step 1 e.g.

- Tokenize each word and process data
- Get all links and process data
- Get all images and process data etc.

To speed up the process I thought of running more than 1 script so that I can process all rows faster but then I came to know about concurrency problem. I read Mysql `TRANSACTION` and that this process is a classic example of `TRANSACTION`.

For records all tables are `INNODB` so that I could use `TRANSACTION / LOCK`. If I use `TRANSACTION` then the problem is that each script waits till a complete row process (step 2 takes longer) and then the process takes equally same time as 1 row is processed at one time only !

Can someone suggest, how can I proceed with some other alternative to `TRANSACTION` OR `LOCK` OR some other table structure so that I can process each ROW in `mytable` faster / concurrently by running same PHP script multiple times together ?

I have tried my hands on `SOLR`, `LUCENE` and `SPHINX` and am sorry, but all are too technical for me to use, sorry for this limitation on my end :( .

Comment: The first alternative to TRANSACTION I can think of is NO TRANSACTION. You may gain speed, so long as you're prepared to lose the data integrity that transaction would assure you.

Comment: What is it that you exactly want to do in step2 ?

Comment: Do you really need PHP to do something other in other tables?

Comment: Yes @bestprogrammerintheworld I need PHP for processing the data. You can please consider this as extension to my previously asked question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539380/mysql-query-of-inverted-index-data

Comment: @jahajee.com - I read the quesiton but I don't understand what you want to do in step2. Do you mean you have to some stuff with for example word-documents? Can you give an concrete example or two?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thanks for replying. Step 2 is not the problem ! Its step 1 and 3. What I want to do is that each `SELECT`  query locks only that row per session (STEP 1 in script), so that another session (STEP 1 in another script) is free to `SELECT` another row unlocked and process it. Thus each script only affects 1 row and not lock full table which `TRANSACTION` does. I think @DBHash reply led me to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html . I think thats the one I was looking for. Will revert after some checks . Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `transaction_isolation` level to `READ UNCOMMITTED` to minimize locking. Set it at session level in the php script.

InnoDB by default has `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level.

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-UNCOMMITTED';
```

To know more about the isolation levels check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your exact issue, issue but I give it a try....

You do like this:

```
 1. Query for 1 row with a particular id in `mytable` with column `status=0`
 2. Using that id do something in `other` table(s) 
 3. When done, update `mytable` with`status=1`
```

Can't you do like this instead?

```
 1. Query for all rows in `mytable` with column `status=0`
 2. Save those rows in a temporary table
 3. Iterate the temporary table to do some things in `other` table(s) 
 4. When done, update all rows that should be affected in `mytable` with`status=1` (with TRANSACTIONS)
```

This way you would only have to use TRANSACTIONS when updating. I think this approach would be much faster because you would only have to do only single query for selection.

**UPDATE**

You could always do something like this to create a temporary table with id's that has status zero:

**(First create a table called temptable manually ONE time)**

```
DROP temptable;
INSERT INTO `temptable`( mytable_id )
SELECT  id FROM `mytable`WHERE status = 0
```

Comment: Have never worked on Temporary table till now, will learn it and revert, the problem is I am not sure temoprary table can take such large data. In any case I can take few rows for temporary table and then continue the loop. Let me try it out and thank you for directions.

Comment: @jahajee.com - its no problem using temporary table with that amount of data. The limit lies within storage (harddrive).

Answer (score 0):

What is being done in the 'other' table.  Depending on whether you need external computation you can do this all via a single query with sub selects.  If the computation is based on data in the two tables you can likely write it that way.  SQL doesn't require iteration in most cases, but acts directly on each cross-product tuple of the joined relations.

In short, tell us more about what precisely you're doing in steps 1 & 2 and then we can see.

(Alternatively, you could switch to a DB that support stored procedures and run it that way.)

Comment: MySQL does support stored procedures